# using jquery form plugin with codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I am trying to processed a form through the Jquery Form plugin with a simple validation using the jquery validation plugin
[jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

simply the form stuck at sending and getting the result instead of showing the printed result inside the page it self it send to the action page

```
 var JQUERY4U = {};
 JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
     setupFormValidation: function () {
         $("#addCatgory").validate({
             rules: {
                 categoryname: {
                     required: true,
                     minlength: 5
                 },
                 categoryslug: {
                     required: true,
                     minlength: 5
                 }
             },
             messages: {
                 categoryname: 'Please enter your name',
                 categoryslug: 'Please enter a valid email'
             }
         });
     }
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#addCatgory').AjaxForm({
         url: 'dashboard/categories/add',
         target: '#result',
         beforeSubmit: JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation(),
         success: function (msg) {
             $('#result').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                 $('#result').html(msg);
             });
         }
     });
 });
```

the validation work great no problem with it at it all 
but after validation passed and instead of showing the result into the result div it takes me to blank page with the the success message . 
and this the Controller function .

```
public function add ()
    {
        $data = array();
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->model->insert();
            echo 'welcome';
            exit;
        }

        $data['parent_cats'] = $this->model->get_parent();
        $this->load->view('dashboard/addcategory', $data, FALSE);
    }
```

Comment: could you remove the ending FALSE parameter from view load part in you add() function and try again?

Comment: @JamshidHashimi its the same thing it showing the result in new page

Comment: ok. Another question: Did you use event.preventDefault(); in your submit button?

Comment: the form plugin disable the submitting automatically

Comment: On your `beforeSubmit`, lose the `()`.  You want to pass the function, not call it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the ajaxForm

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click','.submitButton',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#addCatgory').AjaxForm({
         url: 'dashboard/categories/add',
         target: '#result',
         beforeSubmit: JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation(),
         success: function (msg) {
             $('#result').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                 $('#result').html(msg);
             });
         }
     }).submit();
   })
 });
```

Comment: this one not working :) the script still goes to the action page

Comment: how's your form html? Have you tried with an action in the form instead of providing just an url? And are positively sure jQuery is included??

Comment: I've made an edit to the code. Bind a click action to the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your entire `JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation()` function as that should be called only once on DOM ready instead of when you click submit. ([`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) is for initializing the plugin.)

Once initialized, it automatically captures all events including the `click` on submit button.  So you then [use the `submitHandler` callback function to do your Ajax function](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

Assuming everything else inside your `.AjaxForm()` is correct:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#addCatgory").validate({
        rules: {
            categoryname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            categoryslug: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            categoryname: 'Please enter your name',
            categoryslug: 'Please enter a valid email'
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $(form).AjaxForm({
                url: 'dashboard/categories/add',
                target: '#result',
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#result').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                        $('#result').html(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/xMMLC/**